# center BIG div in screen

Tags: html, css

I will try to be specific with this question. I've been searching all over google for the last 2 hours but I don't know how to search to something like this.

I have a big div, dimensions are 10,000 pixels x 10,000 pixels. What i want to do is fill this up with a big photoset (it's for a local website and I want to make like a big digital photo wall).

I can make a dive 10,000px x 10,000px in css, that's not the problem. What I want is: when someone opens the page, the page has to be 'in the middle', so that the photo that's exactly in the middle of the div is also in the middle of the page, so the visistor can go up, down, left and right scrolling to view the rest. I've made a little image to help it.

[image]

**Edit: this is what I got so far**

```
        <div id="hover">hover</div>
    <div id="pinboard-container">
        <div id="pinboard"></div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/etk8478c/

Comment: [this is off topic (#1)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Try writing some code yourself first and then asking questions when you run into specific answerable issues. If you'd like to hire a programmer, try [careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: You will most likely add the "big div" as your `<body id="big-div">` in you css add `#big-div{background-image: url('youpic.jpg'); height: 10000px; width: 10000px}` then to get the screen to ceneter you will need to use javascript and I do not know the correct name for it but try looking up something like "center page using hash location and javascript".

Comment: [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) works in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you actually try to do it first so we can understand what you want to do faster. I think I did what you wanted with CSS but with a smaller div. [JSFiddle](http://tinyurl.com/nmcv6dj)

Here's the important part (Remove the z-index if you don't want the div on top of everything, set the "100" in the margin to half of your div height & width, so in this example the div has a height of 200 and a width of 200.):

```
  position:fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top:50%; 
  left:50%;
  margin:-100px 0 0 -100px;
```